# How to show div with plus and minus icon? div with margin left not working? how to hide/show div text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying the source code, plz check the demo link :

http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/nvR2S/40/

```
$('.expand').click(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width:'73%',
        height:'130px'
    });
    $('.collapse').show();
});
```

Comment: my source code link: http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/nvR2S/40/

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want to achieve, this is barely a question as it is.

Comment: you have not actually asked a question, what is the problem? it is working as expected

Comment: plz check my demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/nvR2S/40/  plz click on left side div, when i click on the link, i need to hide text..

Comment: And your question is??

Comment: how to hide the text, when i collapse the div.

Comment: What text you want to hide? The 'lorem ipsum' inside p element or maybe something else? Please, just explain needed functionality step by step - so we'll be able to help you.

Comment: i want to hide <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>  Step 1: click on the left side dive.  Step 2: show the <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p> step 3: click on the hide link: hide the <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>. thanks

Comment: Ok, hope it should be helpful for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nvR2S/42/ . You just need to hide all your paragraph elements by default (display:none in your css styles) and then show\hide needed items with the help of your jquery code.

Comment: Thank you so much, how to give show link on the div thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to hide all your paragraph elements by default in your css styles:

```
.expand p {
    display: none;
}
```

and then show\hide needed items with the help of your jquery code.

```
$('.expand').click(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width:'73%',
        height:'130px'
    });
    $(this).find('p').show();
    $('.collapse').show();
});

 $('.collapse').on('click',function(e){
     e.stopPropagation()
     $(this).parent('.expand').stop().animate({
         width: '30px',
         height:'130px'
     });
     $(this).prev('p').hide();
     $(this).hide();
 });
```

I've created a demo [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nvR2S/42/) also so please check it.

Comment: Hi how t0 show plus/minus button on div.

Comment: So, instead of hide/show text you want to display some type of +\- icon at the left side?

Comment: correct la i want to show +/- icon at the left side

Comment: Ok, I hope you can try something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvR2S/44/)

Comment: Thank you so much... div="banner" how i can give gab between three div fix to full width container..banner { margin-left:10;margin-right:10;}

Comment: hi i'm trying to show only image, and show + button on the left corner bottom, i'm not able to show button http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/nvR2S/47/

Comment: my latest demo link :http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/nvR2S/50/

Comment: Can you please provide us with needed design (you can create a screenshot or something else)?

Comment: Hi im trying to do similar method this is link http://www.ge.com/b2c all products plz could you check the links thanks.

Comment: @user2845764 seems like you figured it out already, right?